# OnClick show one image, onClick show other image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a mute and unmute function. But I'm not sure how to display an image path through an if statement. 
Currently it is just a button with text that switches back and forth on click.

```
  mute() {
const video = this.refs.video;
const muteButton = this.refs.mute;

if (video.muted === false) {
  video.muted = true;
  muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute"; // this should be where the image is linked
} else {
  video.muted = false;
  muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute"; // this should be where the image is linked
}
```

}

```
<Button ref="mute" onClick={() => this.mute()} color="danger">
     Unmute
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
const muteButton = this.refs.mute;

<Button ref="mute" onClick={() => this.mute()} color="danger">
     { video.muted ? muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute" : muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute" }
</Button>
```

Comment: Please don't overuse refs as it says here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. You can easily manage this with reacts state.

Comment: Yaa, but it's not hard solution. this is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using React, you shouldn't use `innerHTML` for such things. Just use ternary operator for that right in your JSX:

```js
<Button ref="mute" onClick={() => this.mute()} color="danger">
     { video.muted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute' }
</Button>
```

The same thing with image. You can put specific url directly:

```js
<img src={ video.muted ? mutedUrl : unmutedUrl } />
```

Or you CSS class for that:

```js
<Button className={ video.muted ? 'muted' : 'unmuted' } ...>
  ...
</Button>
```

Also, as i can see video is an element as well. It would be better to hold state in `this.state`.

```js
toggle() {
  const { muted } = this.state;

  this.setState({ muted: !muted });
}

render() {
  const { muted } = this.state;

  ...
    <Video muted={ muted } ...>
      ...
    </Video>
    ...
    <Button ...>
      { muted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute' }
    </Button>
  ...
}
```

You can improve your code a bit more by binding `toggle()` function:

```js
// this option is better
toggle = () => {
  ...
};

// or in your constructor add
constructor(props) {
  ...

  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind();
}
```

Then you will be able to get rid of new anonymous function on each render:

```js
<Button onClick={ this.toggle } ...>
  ...
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do keeping a distinction between javascript logic and graphic is to create two css classes:

```
.mute{
   background: //your image with its style
}
.unmute{
  background: //same as above
}
```

and then in the javascript:

```
  function mute() {
     const video = this.refs.video;
     const muteButton = this.refs.mute;

     if (video.muted === false) {
        video.muted = true;
        muteButton.classList.remove("unmute");
        muteButton.classList.add("mute");
     } else {
        video.muted = false;
        muteButton.classList.remove("mute");
        muteButton.classList.add("unmute");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to track your current state via react's [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Please see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-bird-dxbrc).